# how to refresh events on element in jquery (ui)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-draggable

Is there a way to "refresh" events that should apply on elements with jquery?

To explain better here's my case.
I have a `document.ready()` function that does it's jobs on two lists:

List A containing elements with class a, List B containing elements with class b.

I want to let users move using `draggable`/`droppable` elements from list A to List B but in a way that it clones the element using `.clone(true,true)` to list B and classes get replaced using `.removeClass("a")` and `.addClass("b")`. Other way around - elements from B get removed from B when dragged over to List A

The scenario explained above is working only for the elements who are in either of lists when the page loads, however when I clone the object over from A to B, it's draggable still, but it behaves as elem A, to that extent that when trying to drag it, the dragging shadow starts from the original location in List A, not where I've actually started dragging in List. 
With that in mind I need to find a way to "refresh" the newly cloned element in List B to behave like a List B element.

Thank you for your support.

Comment: Please create a code snippet or provide some code so that we can help troubleshoot the problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've managed to fix the issue by running the cloned element through another `draggable()` call.

On initialization I have:

```
$( ".a" ).draggable({ 
    //...settings
});

$( ".b" ).draggable({ 
    //...settings
});
```

and then inside the droppable when finishing everything up, I'll call the same draggable for B again:

```
 $("#B").droppable({
     accept: ".a",
     //...settings
     drop: function(event, ui) {
         var clone = $(ui.draggable).clone()
         clone.removeClass("a");
         clone.addClass("b");
         $("#B").append(clone);
         $(clone).draggable({ 
             //...sameSettings
         });
     }
 });
```

Now the cloned element works as a native B element and everything's functioning properly.

Answer (score 0):

A I can see from your question, you need to turn off events for some elements. For doing that, you can use **[off() method](http://api.jquery.com/off/)** .

For example, please see code below:

**HTML**

```
List A
<ul>
  <li class="draggable">item1</li>
  <li class="draggable">item2</li>
</ul>

List B
<ul class="droppable">

</ul>
```

**JS**

```
$('.draggable').draggable({
  helper: 'clone'
}).click(function() {
  alert($(this).text());
});


$('.droppable').droppable({
  drop: function(ev, ui) {
    // Add element with all events
    var dropElement = ui.draggable.clone(true, true);
    $(this).append(dropElement);

    // Add element without any events
    var dropElementWithoutEvents = ui.draggable.clone(true, true).off();       
    $(this).append(dropElementWithoutEvents);
  }
});
```

`ui.draggable.clone(true, true).off()` removes all events of element that you drag and `click` event isn't fired by clicking on it, but for `dropElement`, it is fired.

[**Online demo (jsFiddle)**](https://jsfiddle.net/ali_soltani/45bLajkp/)

Comment: Your answer does not help as you've missed the point. The first solution in your `droppable` causes the weird behaviour I mentioned in my original post and the second solution is not a solution because I don't want element from A turn dead when moved to B, but start behaving like B.

Comment: @DethoRhyne What do you mean from _I don't want element from A turn dead when moved to B_ ?

Comment: From your demo using .clone(true,true).off() will disable all events for the cloned object. That's not the intended behaviour. It's supposed to behave like a native b element when moved to B. I've managed to resolve the issue and will post an answer soon.